# Boolean Algebra: How to simplify $ab + ac + \bar a \bar b c$ algebraically?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In the boolean logic

$ab + ac + \bar a \bar b c$

is equivalent to the simpler

$ab + \bar b c$

This can be confirmed by looking at the truth table (below).

The $ab$ and $\bar b c$ minterms cover the $ac$ minterm.

My question is, in general/practice, how can one make this simplification algebraically, that is without having to resort to looking at truth table, Karnaugh maps, which set of minterms possibly cover another minterm, etc.

I tried to manipulate $ab + ac + \bar b c$ algebraically, but only got as far as $a(b + c) + \bar b c\ $ or $\ ab + (a + \bar b)c$ and couldn't really simplify further from there.

---

Notation:

- $ab$ means $a \wedge b$
- $a + b$ means $a \vee b$
- $\bar b$ means $\neg b$

Truth table:

| **a** | **b** | **c** |  | ab | ac | ¬b c |  | ab + ac + ¬b c |  | ab + ¬b c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | **0** | **0** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **0** | **0** | **1** |  |  |  | 1 |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| **0** | **1** | **0** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **0** | **1** | **1** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **1** | **0** | **0** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **1** | **0** | **1** |  |  | 1 | 1 |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| **1** | **1** | **0** |  | 1 |  |  |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| **1** | **1** | **1** |  | 1 | 1 |  |  | 1 |  | 1 |

Comment: Try using [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: By breaking $ac = abc + a\bar bc$,
$$ab + ac + \bar a \bar b c = ab+abc + a\bar bc + \bar a \bar b c = ab + \bar b c$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: I use $x'$ rather than $\bar x$ for ease of writing.*

Since the initial expression is ($ab+\cdots$) and the resulting one is also ($ab+\cdots$) let's focus first on the group $X=ac+a'b'c$

Seems factoring $c$ out is the way to go so let's do it $X=(a+a'b')c$

Now we would like to make $b'$ appear, we can replace $1=b+b'$ to get

$X=(a(b+b')+a'b')c = (ab+ab'+a'b')c = (ab+(a+a')b')c = (ab+b')c = abc+b'c$

Now the expression $abc$ is simply swallowed by $ab$ when calculating the resulting $ab+X$ because $abc+ab=ab(c+1)=ab(1)=ab$.

> So maybe try yo remember the trick $1=x+x'$ it is quite handy in boolean logic.

Answer (score 2):

$$ab + ac + \bar{a}\bar{b}c$$
$$= ab + (a + \bar{a}\bar{b})c$$
$$= ab + (a(b + \bar{b}) + \bar{a}\bar{b})c$$
$$= ab + (ab + a\bar{b} + \bar{a}\bar{b})c$$
$$= ab + (ab + (a + \bar{a})\bar{b})c$$
$$= ab + (ab + \bar{b})c$$
$$= ab + abc + \bar{b}c$$
$$= ab(1 + c) + \bar{b}c$$
$$= ab + \bar{b}c$$